# path not found when using templateUrl - angular directive

Tags: html, angularjs, spring-mvc, angularjs-directive

I append my directive on my controller (custom.js) like this:

```
.directive('protocolModal', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/protocol-modal.html'
    };
});
```

I then use it in my `index.html` like so:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addEntry" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <protocol-modal></protocol-modal>

    </div>
</div>
```

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

And my java-controller looks like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class ProtocolController {

    /**
     * Return a form for creating a new Protocol
     * 
     * @param model
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCreateForm(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

The error I end up getting, looks like this

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: now try to this path ../../templates/protocol-modal.html

Comment: @RohitAzad still same error I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for anyone interested:

The trick was to move the `protocol-modal.html` to the `static folder`

Once that was done I could call it like this

```
templateUrl: '/protocol-modal.html'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change templateUrl

```
.directive('protocolModal', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/layout/protocol-modal.html'
    };
});
```